# Radio button failed to format according to stylesheet

Tags: html, css

HTML registration form is created with **gender** option and now CSS failed to format radio buttons in table cells. How to put them in a aesthetic format with the help of external stylesheet?

I have tried **MDN's** guideline to create form and format them using external CSS. MDN suggested with table and table-cell format in the CSS file!

```css
form.form-example {
  display: table;
}

div.form-example {
  display: table-row;
}

label,
input,
select,
option {
  display: table-cell;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form id="registration" action="" , method="post" class="form-example">

  <div class="form-example">
    <h1>Registration Form</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="form-example">
    <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
    <input name="first_name" type="text" id="fname" placeholder="Python" required>
  </div>


  <div class="form-example">
    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
    <input name="last_name" type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Buddha" required>
  </div>


  <div class="form-example">
    <label for="bdate">Date of Birth:</label>
    <input name="dob" type="date" id="bdate">
  </div>

  <div class="form-example">
    <label for="country">Country:</label>
    <select name="country" id="country">
      <option>USA</option>
      <option>Canada</option>
      <option>Mexico</option>
    </select>
  </div>


  <div class="form-example">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" required>
  </div>


  <div class="form-example">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-example">

    <label>Gender:</label>

    <label for="male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male" required>

    <label for="female">Female</label>
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">

    <label for="other">Other</label>
    <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">

  </div>

  <div class="form-example">
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>

</form>
</div>
```

Comment: I would use flexbox (column) it does what you would need if it's not super customized.
Basically: 
`.my-class: { display: flex,
flex: column }`

Comment: @Michael, flex is good idea but it makes format in a single row ! Thanks by the way for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to change your css styles a bit. Because this:

```css
label,input,select,option{
  display: table-cell;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Will make all inputs on the page to be displayed as a table cell and thus there will be the spacing between radio inputs that you don't like.

*I'm sure that there are other options*, but what worked for me was removing your `label,input,select,option` line and adding `.table-cell` class so you can use it freely on any element that should be displayed as a table-cell.

```css
form.form-example{
  display: table;
}

div.form-example{
  display: table-row;
  height: 30px;
}

.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Kuldeep Gadhavi">
  <title>Registration Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<form id ="registration" action="", method="post" class="form-example">

  <div class="form-example">
    <h1>Registration Form</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="form-example">
    <label for="fname" class="table-cell">First Name:</label>
    <input name="first_name" type="text" id="fname" placeholder="Python" required class="table-cell">
  </div>


  <div class="form-example">
    <label for="lname" class="table-cell">Last Name:</label>
    <input name="last_name" type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Buddha" required class="table-cell">
  </div>


  <div class="form-example">
    <label for="bdate" class="table-cell">Date of Birth:</label>
    <input name="dob" clsss="table-cell" type="date" id="bdate">
  </div>

  <div class="form-example">
    <label for="country" class="table-cell">Country:</label>
    <select name="country" class="table-cell" id="country">
      <option>USA</option>
      <option>Canada</option>
      <option>Mexico</option>
    </select>
  </div>


  <div class="form-example">
    <label for="email" class="table-cell">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" required class="table-cell">
  </div>


  <div class="form-example">
    <label for="password" class="table-cell">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" class="table-cell" required>
  </div>

   <div class="form-example">

     <label class="table-cell">Gender:</label>

     <div class="table-cell">
        <label for="male">Male</label>
        <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male" required>

        <label for="female">Female</label>
        <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">

        <label for="other">Other</label>
        <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
    </div>

    </div>

  <div class="form-example table-cell" >
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>

  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The group with radio buttons is inside a div with class `.table-cell` therefore only this div will be rendered as a table cell. The radio inputs inside will remain rendered as inline elements and thus there will be no white-space between them. Also don't forget to add `.table-cell` class to other elements that should be rendered as table cells (so the inputs and labels.. I have also slightly modified the height of the `.form-example`, because I have removed the margin on `.table-cell` class.

Answer (score 1):

```
label,input,select,option{
    display: table-cell;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

This makes every label, input, select and options as cell.[image]

that's why your radio buttons aren't displayed correctly.
you can see that the male, female and other labels are displayed as cell (border property)

removing label tag should fix the problem.
[image]

```
 Male
 <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male" checked>

 Female
 <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">

 Other
 <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
```

By the way, consider using grid or flex for such things.